# passing ajax data values to data-percent pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, highcharts

I am confuse on how to pass or put a value of my data-percent pie chart thru my ajax data from database. I have successfully pass the other fields by using id but in data percent i am confused on how to put the value on data percent for my pie chart. I am using Codeigniter Framework.

Here is what i want. Something like this :
My Ajax code for getting data from database:

```
function showprojectdetails(projectSelected) {
  var studentId = null;
 $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('manager/projects/ProjDetails/')?>/" + projectSelected,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {

          //this is data percent
          $('#progress-pie-chart').html(data['project_percent']);          
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
}
```

and here is my data progress pie chart where i want to put the value of the data percent : Something like this : the data-percent "35.6" is what i want to replace with the value of my project_percent from ajax

```
    <div class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="35.6"><!--Pie Chart -->
 <div class="ppc-progress">
 <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="ppc-percents">
 <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
 <span>%</span>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `$('.progress-pie-chart').html(data['project_percent']);`?

Comment: @Jc John $('#projectPercent').html instead of use $(".progress-pie-chart").html

Comment: thanks for answer .. i'll try it

Comment: PHP might not generate pie charts as fast as JavaScript's Canvas API, since the images have to be loaded back to the Browser. Just a heads up.

Comment: @Elangovan thank you for your answer. it doesn't i tried it like this 

$('.progress-pie-chart').html(data['project_percent']);

Comment: @madalinivascu sir it doesn't, i tried it like this : 
$('.progress-pie-chart').html(data['project_percent']);

Comment: Are you using Highcharts in your project? I cannot find it inside your AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in your success function

```
options.series[0].data = data['project_percent'];//set the data
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);//create the chart here
```

Comment: sir it doesn't. please help :( 

options.series[0].data = data['project_percent'];
         var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

Comment: success: function(data) {
         options.series[0].data = data['project_percent'];//set the data
         var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);//create the chart here         
        }

Comment: sir i already edited it sir, the data-percent:35.6 percent sir. i want to replace it with the ajax value of  project_percent

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".progress-pie-chart").attr('data-percent', value);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir i tried this, but this doesn't work 

$(".progress-pie-chart").attr('data-percent', data['project_percent']);

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".